# Tomcat 6 response writing

Tags: tomcat6

I am observing strange behavior of my tomcat server, it seems like tomcat is not writing response to the client fast enough. Here is what I am seeing:

When firing aound 200 requests at the same time at my tomcat server, my application logs shows that my servlet's doGet() finishes process the request in about 500ms. However, at the client side the average response time is about 30 seconds (which means client start seeing response from tomcat after 30 seconds)!

Does anyone have any idea about how come there are such long delay between the end of my servlet's process time and the time when client receives response?

My server is hosted on Rackspace VM.

Answer (score 0):

Found the culprit. I observed that the hosting server was using abnormally high CPU usage for even for only few requests, so I attached JConsole to Tomcat and found that all my worker thread has high blocking count... and are constantly in blocking state. Looking at the stack trace the locking happened during JAXBContext instantiation. Digg further, the application creating JAXBContext, which is relatively expensive, for each request.

So in summary, the problem was caused by JAXBContext instantiation per thread. Solution was to ensure JAXBContext is created once per application.